# How should I use @Cacheable on spring data repositories

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data

When using, for example, `MongoRepository` there are some methods which I would like to mark as `@Cacheable` such as `insert(entity)` or `findOne(id)`. 
Since it's a Spring repository and not mine, how should I use `@Cacheable` on those methods?

Comment: What's your purpose of caching? Do you want to reduce DB read access or what?

Comment: Usually this is the main purpose of caching, yes.

Comment: So, you followed the docs I assume. What did not work?

Comment: I will elaborate: spring MongoRepository extends other spring repositories interfaces. One of those interfaces includes the method getOne(String id) . Do I need to add @Cacheable inside spring interfaces? I doubt. Since I use the MongoRepository as is, where should I place the cache annotations?

Comment: Add the annotation to your service layer, to the methods that call the Spring Data repositories.

Comment: I was hoping to skip the service layer. Although not the best practice, I just need pure crud over rest. In that case I have no use for service layer. Unfortunately, as it seems, I will have to implement a "cache" layer.

Comment: But... what IS the problem? The obvious way to do it is to extend `MongoRepository` and add `@Override` and `@Cacheable` to the methods you want to cache, [as per the official example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa-examples/blob/master/spring-data-jpa-example/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/example/repository/caching/CachingUserRepository.java). Why isn't this an option?

Comment: For start, MongoRepository is an interface. you cannot add @Override to its methods.

Comment: Spring recommends that you only annotate concrete classes (and methods of concrete classes) with the @Cache* annotation, as opposed to annotating interfaces.  https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#cache-annotation-enable

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not sure how you're actually using `MongoRepository`, you seem to be suggesting you're using it directly *(it's often a good idea to include your code in the question)*, but the reference documentation explains the basics of working with this interface (and all repository interfaces in Spring Data, as a matter of fact): ["§ 6.1. Core concepts"](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/1.7.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories.core-concepts):

> *(...)* This interface acts primarily as a marker interface to capture the types to work with and to help you to discover interfaces that extend this one. *(...)*

Your custom repository would be something like:

```
public interface SomeTypeMongoRepository extends MongoRepository<SomeType, Long> {
    @Override
    @CacheEvict("someCache")
    <S extends SomeType> S insert(S entity);

    @Override
    @Cacheable("someCache")
    SomeType findOne(Long id);
}
```

(note that it's based on the [official example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/blob/0ddb2ba0d6529f0554d498bb72bab5d01b33b6ac/jpa/example/src/main/java/example/springdata/jpa/caching/CachingUserRepository.java) I included in one of my comments)

Answer (score 1):

One of the options could be to do it in xml, as explained in the [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html#cache-declarative-xml).

Another benefit of this approach is that you can make multiple methods cacheable with a single declaration.

Comment: Its the same approach as adding a service layer and declare cache annotations on its methods. I wanted to escape the service layer as I dont need one.